# Set navigation bar item style in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationbar

When adding a navigation bar item with UIKit, you set its style with [UIBarButtonItem.style](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617114-style). This is important for a [Done](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/style/done) button, which is displayed with bold text.

SwitftUI's [navigationBarItems(leading:trailing:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3340829-navigationbaritems) takes a `View` but no style. You could hack a style look-alike by using a bold button in the view, but it won't adjust to future OS style changes (e.g. a [font weight](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/weight) other than `bold`).

How do you set the navigation bar item's style with SwiftUI?

Comment: I assume that all SwiftUI navigation bar items are handled as customView items (excepting, probably, standard Back button), so if you specify some having style bold, it will always be bold.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### iOS 14+

It is worth noting that using `ToolbarItem(placement:)` within a `toolbar` modifier will automatically apply emboldened text to buttons in the `.confirmationAction` placement position.

For example:

```
struct MyView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Form {
        // other elements
      }
      .navigationTitle("Edit Publication")
      .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
          Button("Cancel") { }
        }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
          Button("Save") { }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see from the illustration below, the **Save** button appears in bold.

[image: Toolbar with contextually emboldened buttons]

If you want a button in the same place as the **Save** button below but not to be emphasised, you'd use the `.primaryAction` modifier.

Using the placement types that describe toolbar items' context – rather than using the deprecated `navigationBarItems` modifier, or the `.navigationBarTrailing` and `.navigationBarLeading` placement values – is the best way to make your SwiftUI views adapt to any changes in future versions of iOS.

They're also applicable across multiple platforms that don't necessarily have navigation bars, and other platforms may choose to render them differently. For example, using `.confirmationAction` on macOS creates a button with the app `accentColor` as a background.

Answer (score 6):

I think we have to change how we think about SwiftUI as the concepts of "UIBarButtonItem.style" won't be directly applicable. SwiftUI tries to hide implementation details and wants concepts like changing the font-weight to "auto-magically work" depending on the context.

On Xcode 12.3, and iOS 14.3, seems that by default the button styles are bold ***(in the context of NavigationView)***:

```
.navigationBarItems(
  leading:
    Button(action: {}) {
      Text("Cancel")
  },
  trailing:
    Button(action: {}) {
      Text("Save")
    }
  )
```

One way to change styling is by adding a button style:

```
.navigationBarItems(
  leading:
    Button(action: {}) {
      Text("Cancel")
    }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()),
  trailing:
    Button(action: {}) {
      Text("Save")
    }
  )
```

But that did not achieve the desired effect. **I had to change the font weight to have the "Cancel" be a regular style**, and "Save" be bold...just like standard iOS:

```
.navigationBarItems(
  leading:
    Button(action: {}) {
      Text("Cancel")
        .fontWeight(Font.Weight.regular)
    },
  trailing:
    Button(action: {}) {
      Text("Save")
    }
  )
```

The nice thing about this is that you don't need to know about the concept of "UIBarButtonItem.style:" you just need to know about the concepts of what a `Button` is, and what `Text` is - which API should be familiar over-time as they are standard building blocks.

[image]

Comment: Good observation about the OS version differences. To get an experience similar to the Apple apps across all OS versions, you have to set both the regular and bold font weights. What a mess! Not only do you have to work at the font-weight level of abstraction, there's not even a stable default. UIKit's approach of having you indicate whether or not a button is a "Done" button is much better.

Answer (score -2):

in SwiftUI instead of passing a style you append it to the View component. this will adjust to future OS style changes:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View{
    NavigationView {
      Text("blah")
        .navigationBarItems(leading: Text("done button")
          .fontWeight(.medium)
          .bold()
          .foregroundColor(Color.red))
    }
  }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Comment: Your code sample is applying `fontWeight`, `bold`, and `foregroundColor` to `Text`, not to the navigator bar item. It seems unlikely that iOS will ever automatically adjust such specifically applied properties. I don't think iOS even changes the shade of red when you switch to dark mode. Can you point to where the behavior you expect is documentated?